# Convert ntlm to aes256 in sekurlsa::pth

Tags: mimikatz

In mimikatz, `sekurlsa::pth` also supports `/aes256` switch. But how can I get the aes256 hash?

I can retrieve NTLM hash from many different tools. Is there any way to convert it to an aes256 one?

Answer (score 3):

In short, no you cannot *convert* NTLM to AES. NTLM is a hashing function vs AES, which is an encryption algorithm (*see @MikeOunsworth answer for more on this*).

To recover the AES version of the password, the Domain needs to be configured to store them as such **and** you'd recover them by dumping the ntds.dit (Active Directory User Hive backup). Then you can use secretsdump.py or similar tool to extract the AES versions. Now that said, you'll need Domain Admin (or equivalent permissions) to dump ntds.dit (from a Domain Controller), so PTH may not be needed if you have that level of perms, but you *could* do it nonetheless.

**EDIT**

Here's what each version looks like when recovered from ntds.dit

```
WAKANDA$:5136:aad3__LM-HASH__d3b435b54ee:f1e03f8f94__NTLM-HASH__f0c0df:::
WAKANDA$:aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96:8941c28ac__snip__8a51adf13336b
WAKANDA$:aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96:cbe71ab9b__snip__2dc21d6
WAKANDA$:des-cbc-md5:576_snip_bcec
WAKANDA$:rc4_hmac:f1e036ef8f__snip__69cf0c0df
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two questions in there. I'll answer this one:

> I can retrieve NTLM hash from many different tools, is there any way to convert it to a aes256 one?

First off, the NT/LM hashes are hash functions that take a message to produce a hash, while AES is a block cipher that takes a message *and a key* to produce a cipher-text. These things generally serve different purposes (for example, hashes are often used with passwords, block ciphers are not). I'm not an NTLM expert, but it seems suspicious that you would want to convert from one to the other.

Second, from [this article](http://www.adshotgyan.com/2012/02/lm-hash-and-nt-hash.html) we have:

> The LM hash is a very weak one-way function used for storing passwords. Originally invented for the LAN Manager operating system, the LM hash was included in Windows NT for backward compatibility. It is still included for backward compatibility. Because of the way the LM hash is calculated, no password with an LM hash is stronger than a 7-character password selected from a 142-character character set.

which tells us that it's a cryptographic one-way hash function (albeit an obsolete and weak one). Converting an NTLM hash to something else would first require you to brute-force crack the hash to recover the plaintext.

---

Bottom line: you should probably do a little more reading about what NTLM hashes and AES are, and maybe things will become a bit more clear for you.

Comment: I know that. I think the aes256 is an encrypted value from the NTLM hash. Otherwise is reversible.

Comment: What key are you using to encrypt the NTLM hash? (again, I'm not an expert here, just asking questions)

Comment: Usually the bootkey, but it's more complex than that ...